Getting Desktop Icon's positions with pywin32 (Python)
I've been trying to get the X and Y of the icons on the desktop screen however none of the solutions I've tried seem to give the desired outcome "Icon: {Name} (X,Y)" or something along those lines.
Code I've tried
I've tried this code however it only seems to give attributes of the file rather than anything relating to X,Y coords
import win32com.client

shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("Shell.Application")
desktop_folder = shell.NameSpace(0)
desktop_items = shell.NameSpace(0).Items()

# Loop through all desktop icons and perform some action
for i in range(desktop_items.Count): 
    item = desktop_items.Item(i)
    
    recieved = desktop_folder.GetDetailsOf(item, SOME_INDEX) # E.g. 0 gives the Name of the file

I've also tried looking at ways of changing this code to implement LVM_GETITEMPOSITION which I presume is what I need to get these coords. However (most likely due to my lack of knowledge in interfacing with win32) I can't seem to get that working and the best I got was a bunch of zeros.
And finally I also looked at other stackoverflow articles though they were mostly in other (programming) languages (in which I didn't know how to convert from) or took me to another article which then took me to another one until I was back full circle..
Stackoverflow articles I've looked at:

How to move desktop icons with python? (Got working however didn't know how to change bytes strings into coordinates)
How to move desktop icons using winapi on C? (Moves icons not gets pos)
How to get the windows desktop icons position in python? (redirected me to nothing useful)
LVM_GETITEMPOSITION (No accepted answer)

and many more which I won't list out

This answer is correct and gets you all the way to finding the folder view. You just need to replace the call to IFolderView::SelectAndPositionItems() with IFolderView::GetItemPosition().

[SO]: How to move desktop icons with python? (@CristiFati's answer) (mentioned in the question) contains all the needed pieces (including what you weren't able to figure out: folder_view.GetItemPosition(item)): 2 separate scripts that one has to (somehow) combine.
Note: As specified in my other answer, the 1st PyWin32 official version containing IFolderView functionality is v307.
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import pythoncom
import win32com.client as wcomcli
from win32com.shell import shell, shellcon


SWC_DESKTOP = 0x08
SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH = 0x01

CLSID_ShellWindows = "{9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39}"
IID_IFolderView = "{CDE725B0-CCC9-4519-917E-325D72FAB4CE}"


def main(*argv):
    shell_windows = wcomcli.Dispatch(CLSID_ShellWindows)
    hwnd = 0
    dispatch = shell_windows.FindWindowSW(
        wcomcli.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_I4, shellcon.CSIDL_DESKTOP),
        wcomcli.VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_EMPTY, None),
        SWC_DESKTOP, hwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH,
    )
    service_provider = dispatch._oleobj_.QueryInterface(pythoncom.IID_IServiceProvider)
    browser = service_provider.QueryService(shell.SID_STopLevelBrowser, shell.IID_IShellBrowser)
    shell_view = browser.QueryActiveShellView()
    folder_view = shell_view.QueryInterface(IID_IFolderView)
    items_len = folder_view.ItemCount(shellcon.SVGIO_ALLVIEW)
    desktop_folder = shell.SHGetDesktopFolder()
    print(f"Found {items_len} items\n")
    for i in range(items_len):
        item = folder_view.Item(i)
        print(f"Item {i:2d}\n"
              #f"  Id: {item}\n"
              f"  Name: {desktop_folder.GetDisplayNameOf([item], shellcon.SHGDN_NORMAL)}\n"
              f"  Position: {folder_view.GetItemPosition(item)}"
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Output:


(My comment got deleted for some reason)
Due to IFolderView not being implemented I'm wondering than how yours gave an output.
As I tried running the code and as expected it got caught on trying to initialize folder_view. Did you just make a mockup with print to show how the expected output would be once implemented or is it a bug with it not working on my system?
(Here's the error if you were wondering:
folder_view = shell_view.QueryInterface(IID_IFolderView) TypeError: There is no interface object registered that supports this IID)

In my other answer I explained (with links to another one) how to apply a patch locally and build (parts of) PyWin32. Your statement "Got working however didn't know how to change bytes strings into coordinates" implies that you already did the same thing, and that's why I started from there.

Yes, apologies. I do recall the script working.. however I have lost the original file.. and by my recollection I don't recall building/applying the patch as you have done. So to be honest I'm completely lost with how I got it working and don't fully understand how to apply the patch myself.
However I would like to thank you for helping and dealing with my (most likely) stupidity on the topic of pywin32.
If you have any further help/explanation it would be greatly appreciated though if you would like I can just mark your solution ✅ since it works for others whom now more about the subject.

If you didn't build a version of the code that contains my patch into PyWin32 (or shell.pyd), things couldn't possibly work, as the functionality didn't exist before. There's no question of stupidity here, it's a complex package with lots of stuff. Technically this is not a solution yet, since it involves this build step which is not scalable (you could do it on your PC for example). Usually PyWin32 releases occur every 6 months, but it's more than a year since the last one. Building it (python setup.py bdist_wheel) has a lots of dependencies.

Original message was buggying out and I couldn't edit it.. Sorry for the extra ping)
I just wanna check how I would build it? My guess is going into the main files of pywin32 and adding the modifications shown here: GithubCommit tho I just wanted to check if there is a better way of achieving this? Since you state python setup.py bdist_wheel. Just wanted to check so that I don't corrupt files or smth.

The build process is a bit tricky (there is a description on GitHub). I asked them when will a new release be available: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/2294.
